# Pulling data from Quickbase for Highcharts.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Ok so I am trying to make a basic bar chart using highcharts and I am trying to use data that is contained in a QuickBase database, I have managed to pull the data from the server, I used an API call and have the data using this

http://pastebin.com/fJry1jA8

```
    <!Doctype html>         
    <html>         
    <head>
    </head>         
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.src.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.src.js"></script>         

    <script>         
    var dbidApplication = "-EDITED OUT-";
    var dbidTable = "-EDITED OUT-";
    var apptoken = "-EDITED OUT-";

    $.ajaxSetup({data: {apptoken: apptoken}});

    var promise1 = $.get(dbidApplication , {
      a: "dbpage",
      pagename: "chart.html"
    });         

    var promise2 = $.get(dbidTable, {
      act: "API_GenResultsTable",
      query: "{14.EX.'_FID_9}",
      clist: "7.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.31.32.33.34.35.36.37",
      jsa: 1,
      options: "num-1",
    });         

    $.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(chartArgs, dataArgs) {
      var chart = chartArgs[0];
      var markup = new Highcharts.Chart(chart, qdb_data);
      console.log(markup);
    });

    </script>    

     <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>  

<script>    
    $(function () { 
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
         renderTo: 'container',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    });

    </script>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've looked up examples of what people have told me, but now I am confused between being told I need to parse,pluck,get,and a list of other things that I have no clue what to look into so I can actually use this data, but I am looking for an explanation of whats actually going on also (I really don't find it helpful to see a bunch of code where half of it I don't understand because I haven't learned to that yet, its rather depressing)

Comment: can you paste the output of your response. Also there is an example on highcharts that explains how to use your ajax loaded content in the graphs. [link](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JPJWah3H      Also I suppose I missed the explanation for that. I'll check it out now.

Comment: So here. Whats your X-axis and Y-axis ? And can you paste the RAW response, just a sample of it will be okay too.

Comment: That error states you do not have a target div to put the chart svg into. There is also no highcharts code in your pastebin.

Comment: Appologies, but I'm not sure I get what you mean by the raw response (I don't have a whole lot of experience) Also, the X axis will be what is [17]-[30], and the Y axis is the concentration of those.         What I am aiming for is a graph that gets the records of a users selected "station" and then takes and graphs it based on the 5 most recent dates where the station number matches, making the compounds comparable over time.

Comment: Also wergeld, I have not actually made my own highchart code, I am just trying to figure out how exactly I could get my data to where it could be easily implemented into the chart (and still remain reusable for every other station)

Comment: Highcharts requires an HTML target div: `<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>`  You don't have it.  Read this carefully: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart, also wrap your JS in `$(function () {`